# Accuracy capped in Keras neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am feeding a neural network lists of numbers to predict a single float output. The training data is normalized. I used the Keras built in normalize for the feature training data and mapped the labels from 0 to 1. For some reason my accuracy either gets worse or just sits at 0.1638 (an oddly specific value...) Ive tried tons of different learning rates and activations. I am using RMS for the loss function.

Heres a sample of the normalized x_train:

```
[0.06258409 0.25033637 0.18775228 0.62584093 0.21904432 0.57890286 0.15646023 0.03129205 0.18775228 0.25033637]
```

So that looks fine to me, but using this model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(feature_count,)))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='elu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The accuracy usually looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtBCA.png)

When I finally got it to improve it capped at 0.1638 like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYzof.png)

Why does this model hate this data? Is the data just garbage? (I did get it from Kaggle...)

Comment: There are several things wrong with this question. For starters, you are using MSE loss function, not RMSE. Second, you are using an elu activation in the final layer, which gives an activation range of <-1, inf>. What is the range of your output supposed to be? Finally, what does the data mean? If there is no relation between inputs and output, the system can't learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is doing regression, it makes no sense to use accuracy int that case. Accuracy is only valid for classification problems.

Comment: You are right, sorry I'm new to ML. That still doesn't fix my model :(